# Money value to words jquery

Tags: javascript

Following [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm) tutorial i was able to convert number value to words. But i want to change money value not only numbers so i manipulated it a bit like this

```
// Convert numbers to words
// copyright 25th July 2006, by Stephen Chapman http://javascript.about.com
// permission to use this Javascript on your web page is granted
// provided that all of the code (including this copyright notice) is
// used exactly as shown (you can change the numbering system if you wish)

// American Numbering System
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
// uncomment this line for English Number System
// var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var str1 = ''; //i added another word called cent
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'and '; //i change the word point to and 
        str1 += 'cents '; //i added another word called cent
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ' ;
    }
    //return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') + str1; //i added the word cent to the last part of the return value to get desired output
}
```

But i have problem that i can figure out myself problem is as follows

```
When i want to convert this money value `9.01` i will get this -> nine and zero one cents But what i want/need is to make it look like -> `nine and one cent`
When i want to convert this money value `9.10` i will get this -> nine and one cents But what i want/need is to make it look like -> `nine and ten cents`
When i want to convert this money value `9.11` i will get this -> nine and one one cents But what i want/need is to make it look like -> `nine and eleven cents`
When i want to convert this money value `9.12` i will get this -> nine and one two cents But what i want/need is to make it look like -> `nine and twelve cents`
```

Comment: what is your question? "But i have problem that i can figure out myself "

Comment: There is no jQuery in this. It's pure JS.

Comment: Where your question? and where the jquery? and could you provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: in the as follows part. I want to show the text like the one in `expects` but currently it is showing the wrong output. in the tutorial there is a sample on how it will look like i didnt make a fiddle because i dont know how to put a external js in fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below working code snipped.

```js
// Convert numbers to words
// copyright 25th July 2006, by Stephen Chapman http://javascript.about.com
// permission to use this Javascript on your web page is granted
// provided that all of the code (including this copyright notice) is
// used exactly as shown (you can change the numbering system if you wish)

// American Numbering System
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
// uncomment this line for English Number System
// var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {

    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
 var fulllength=s.length;
 
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
 var startpos=fulllength-(fulllength-x-1);
    var n = s.split('');
 
    var str = '';
    var str1 = ''; //i added another word called cent
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';

                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        
        str += 'and '; //i change the word point to and 
        str1 += 'cents '; //i added another word called cent
        //for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ' ;
   var j=startpos;
  
   for (var i = j; i < fulllength; i++) {
   
        if ((fulllength - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
    
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
  
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((fulllength - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((fulllength - i) % 3 == 1) {
  
            if (sk) str += th[(fulllength - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    }
 var result=str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') + str1;
    //return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
 $('.res').text(result);
    return result; //i added the word cent to the last part of the return value to get desired output
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="convert"></input>

<button onclick="toWords($('.convert').val())">Click me</button>

<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: i need clarification when there is no cents. I need to get rid of `AND CENTS` i cant find a way.